# Is there any notification to inform when voice over has finished reading a button or a label?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, accessibility, voiceover

The notification UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification do not work. It can only work by using UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, string). So how can I find when the voice over finished reading a button.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In other words, what do you want to do after VoiceOver as finished reading?

Comment: keep in mind that the voiceover user can change the speed of reading too